# coded ui - controlling windows phone keyboard sip

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I need to enter some data into a silverlight app. I am trying to do this by pulling up sip and   enter data using raw Gesture.Tap().

Even though the sip keyboard and buttons are detected (as using UIA) by coded UI test builder,  I am unable to access it. Calling Find() on the button just hangs.

Thanks